# Frame when expression in jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to write "when" expression on the frame in jasper report.
Purpose : there is lot of elements (textfield,statictext,line rectangle) in the frame. then i want to remove all this based on a variable, so i can avoid that blank space.

Comment: When i wrote **"Print when expression"** for each **element** and set true **"Remove line when blank"** for **frame**. in the output the blank space still there ...

Comment: You cat set PrintWhenExpression for frame, not for each element.

Comment: Are u sure the blank space is because of the element was still there? maybe its already hidden but the other element doesn't move to that location. And what do u put the expression for `Print when expression`?

Comment: "Print when expression"  $V{PAGE_NUMBER}==1 . means only for fisrt page

Comment: hei sanbez . that's also not working ....

Answer (score 1):

You have set "**Print when expression**" for **each element** and "**remove line when blank" for frame component**.

Instead, try this. Set "**Print when expression**" for **Frame component** and enable "**remove line when blank**" for both **frame component and each component** inside frame component.

Hope this should work.